# Sum into blank cell while summing all above until next blank cell, in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet

I've got this spreadsheet in which I need to Sum up worked hours.
In Column 'I' I've got all worked hours which I sorted through weeknumbers in row 'E' with the following loop I found somewhere on Google (can't remember who wrote it but it works).

```
Dim i, itotalrows As Integer
Dim strRange As String

itotalrows = ActiveSheet.Range("E20000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row


Do While i <= itotalrows
    i = i + 1
    strRange = "E" & i
    strRange2 = "E" & i + 1
    If Range(strRange).Text <> Range(strRange2).Text Then
        Rows(i + 1).Insert
        itotalrows = ActiveSheet.Range("E20000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        i = i + 1
    End If

Loop
```

In the picture you can see one of the cells marked with "Total value of cells up
"
there's a blank every few rows with a cell on 'I' where the total value should go.

Sheet Picture:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps to sum the groups in column I, based on where the blanks are in column G

```
Sub x()

Dim r As Range

For Each r In Range("G:G").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Areas
    r.Cells(r.Count + 1).Offset(, 2).Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(r.Offset(, 2))
Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: If this answer helped you please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).  Accepting answers rewards the contributor and helps those that follow you to find a working solution.  @SJR - really neat little solution.  +1.

Comment: Thank you @destination-data.

Comment: This almost works perfectly. I quickly double checked but the some of the sums aren't right either. The first two groups have this value in the cells where the total sum should be: 1/1/1900  06:00:00. Also at some groups  if there's 3 cells all with the value of 01:00, it outputs things like 00:10. Though it should be 03:00.

Comment: Probably just a formatting issue. Try formatting the whole column as you want.

Comment: Yes! it works if I use the 37:30:55 time format. If I add this to the end of the code, will column I be formatted in 37:30:55? `Range("I:I").NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"`

Comment: Good. Yes that should work if that's the format you are using.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to replace your code with the following, I believe it should do what you expect:

```
Sub foo()
Dim i, itotalrows As Integer
Dim strRange As String

itotalrows = ActiveSheet.Range("E20000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

Do While i <= itotalrows
    i = i + 1
    strRange = "E" & i
    strRange2 = "E" & i + 1
    If Range(strRange).Text <> Range(strRange2).Text Then
        Rows(i + 1).Insert
        Cells(i + 1, "I").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF(C[-4],R[-1]C[-4],C)"
        'when inserting a new row, simply add this formula to add up the values on column I
        itotalrows = ActiveSheet.Range("E20000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        i = i + 1
    End If
Loop
End Sub
```

Seeing as your code already does what you wanted (ie. add a new row when values on Column E differ) then adding the formula into that row will add up anything on Column I where the value of Column E is the same.

Comment: This one seems to work the best, but the output is not correct. e.g, if there's 3 cells all with the value of 01:00, it outputs things like 00:10. Though it should be 03:00..

Answer (score 0):

This is a general approach how to sum the cells in the blank cell.
If this is the input then the right ppicture should be the output:

[image]
.
[image]

Using this code:

```
Sub TestMe()    
    Dim myCell      As Range
    Dim currentSum  As Double        
    For Each myCell In Worksheets(1).Range("A1:A14")
        If myCell = vbNullString Then
            myCell = currentSum
            myCell.Interior.Color = vbRed
            currentSum = 0
        Else
            currentSum = currentSum + myCell
        End If
    Next myCell           
End Sub
```

The idea is simply to use a variable for the currentSum and to write it every time when the cell is empty. If it is not empty, increment it with the cell value

Comment: I get a type mismatch error (run-time error 13) what does that mean?

Comment: @VincentGerrits - it means that somewhere you are having a non-numeric character (e.g. a lettter). Restart your PC, open a new Excel, write the values as they are, copy the code above and run it. It should work fine.